# Program is getting crashed when using getch and getche

Tags: arrays, c, string, while-loop, getch

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define max 100

void compare(char *name,char* input);

int main()
{
int i=0;
char name[max]="santosh";
char input[max];
printf("enter the password\n");
while((input[i]=getchar())!='\n'){
    i++;
}
input[i]='\0';

compare(name,input);

return 0;
}
void compare(char *name,char* input){
     while((*name==*input)&&(*name!='\0'&&*input != '\0')){
    *name++;
    *input++;
    }
   if(*name=='\0'&&*input=='\0')
   printf("Correct Password");
   else
   printf("Incorrect Password");

}
```

This Program is getting crashed in vs code but when I use getchar() instead of getch() or getche() all is working fine.
Why it is not working with getch() and how it will run as I want user to insert a password and thus want to use getch() not getchar().

Comment: Your users will not be running inside VSCode.  That's the difference.  Run it in a real cmd console and it should work with getch.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `#define max` generates a warning "macro redefinition", so change that.

The second problem is that `getch()` and `getche` do not convert the **Enter** key to 'newline' `\n` but to 'return' `\r`

The third problem is that instead of incrementing the pointers, you are incrementing what they point to.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAXX 100                            // fixed macro name collision

void compare(char *name, char* input);

int main(void)                              // corrected definition
{
    int i = 0;
    char name[MAXX] = "santosh";
    char input[MAXX];
    printf("enter the password\n");
    while((input[i] = getche()) != '\r') {  // fixed '\n' check
        i++;
    }
    input[i] = '\0';
    compare(name, input);
    return 0;
}

void compare(char *name,char* input){

    while(*name == *input && *name != '\0' && *input != '\0') {
        name++;                             // fixed pointer increment
        input++;                            // fixed pointer increment
    }
    
    if(*name == '\0' && *input == '\0')
        printf("Correct Password\n");
    else
        printf("Incorrect Password\n");
}
```

Finally you should also check `i` does not exceed the array bounds. The strings seem long enough, but not for players who try to break the program.